# Are all hooks/functions tied to Kses meant for sanitization?

Tags: php, hooks, core, sanitization

I'm currently learning WordPress hooks and am delving into core to see what's happening in there. I noticed there are filters in wp-includes/default-filters.php with PHP comments about Kses. I wasn't sure what Kses meant until I found [wp_kses](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) in the Codex.

The notes on this page says:

> KSES is a recursive acronym which stands for “KSES Strips Evil
>   Scripts".

So then do I assume anything I find in core with either kses in the code or the PHP comments has to do with data sanitization? Just trying to understand general patterns in WordPress core. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... anything I find in core with either kses in the code or the PHP
>   comments has to do with data sanitization?

It would have to do with the functions that sanitize data or with data that needs to be sanitized, yes. That is the primary reason for the KSES code, which, if you look it over, is pretty resource intensive. You wouldn't want to use it unnecessarily.

Comment: Hmm, am I right to assume then from what I see in default-filters.php that wp_kses_data is mostly used in admin sanitization whereas wp_filter_kses is for front-end?